# Android set default device theme

Tags: android, android-layout

I've an app which may be ran from 2.2 to 4.x devices.

When I run this app on 4.x it looks cool, holo style. But when I run it on older devices, it seems to be so much "lighty".

There's a screenshot so you can compare:
[image]

This is my manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

And my styles:

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">

</style>
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

It's obvious that holo doesn't exist in 2.3, but then it should render its default device theme, right?

So the input is correct, but the TextView looks **too grey.**

Any idea?

Comment: It doesn't look very grey here in your screenshot... By the way, you may find this interesting: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere

Comment: Not the hint, the title top from the input, left is black, right is grey..

Comment: "It's obvious that holo doesn't exist in 2.3, but then it should render its default device theme, right?" -- ideally, you use versioned style resources (e.g., `res/values/`, `res/values-v11/`), so you control *specifically* what base theme is used on pre-Holo devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone suggested, I finally created a new folder:
`res/values-v11/`
On this folder, I've put a file named `styles.xml`, which is the following:

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">

</style>
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

And the folder `res/values/` which will be called for android with api lower than 11, contains a `styles.xml` and there I've changed the parent template, like this:

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">

</style>
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

This ends up like this:

- Devices with api higher than 11 -> holo theme
- The rest: Theme.Light ("Normal theme")